# MYSQL- How to sum values from one table into one field in another table?

Tags: mysql

everyone, I'm making a blood bank donation system database. So I've made a table

```
donation
(
id donation int, 
blood_type varchar(45), 
blood_amount float
)
```

and a second table 
blood_supply
(
blood_type varchar(45), 
amount_by_type float
)

My table Looks like this

[image]

in which I want to store the overall blood from all the donations by blood type.

So now I tried to sum the values from my donation table based on the blood_type and store them into the blood_supply table using :

```
    update donation,blood_supply 
set amount_by_type = (amount_by_type + blood_amount) 
where donation.blood_type = blood_supply.blood_type;
```

but it didn't sum the blood_amount correctly.

I got this

[image]

insted of getting A = 0.8, B = 0.4, 0 = 0.9 in the blood_supply table

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and MySQL. Which is correct?

Comment: It's mysql sorry

Comment: Chimeras aside, how does a donation donate more than one type of blood?

Comment: I corrected that later every donation has it's own id ofc :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to aggregate the left table first before join and update the right table.

```
update (select sum(blood_amount) blood_amount,
        blood_type
        from donation
        group by blood_type) dt, 
        blood_supply bs
set bs.amount_by_type = dt.blood_amount
where bs.blood_type = dt.blood_type
```

Hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is a view. It is not practical to update one table each time you modify data in another table.

My answer would be:

```
create view blood_supply  as select sum(blood_amount) as blood_amount, blood_type
        from donation group by blood_type
```

After this, blook_supply can be handled like any other table for reading, but it will update the values as donation changes. Change means new donations, update of existing, or deletes.